# Ошибка в запросе "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in"

Tags: mysql

При выполнении запроса вот выходит такая ошибка

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in
```

Запрос вот:

```
 $sql='select a.id, b.city_lng, b.city_lat from t_city as a,
            t_city_coord as b where a.id=b.city_id and a.city_name_rus="'.$city_name.'"';
      $res=mysql_query($sql) or die mysql_error;
```

Делаю такой в `phpmyadmin` - работает прекрасно. База подключена, так как после этого запроса там еще будет несколько и работают они хорошо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$res=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

[die()](https://www.php.net/die)

Comment: ой ну надо же было мне так тупануть.спасибки

Comment: @Евгения Форманюк
, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: вот теперь определилась реальная ошибка: SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 't_city'